# Is there a way to do bulk insert in Postgresql from node.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bulkinsert

I'm using `pg` module (and the promise version `pg-promise-strict`).

When I need to insert 1k records I must send to the server one by one.

I can't build a 1k record INSERT because my organization policies: the data MUST be sended separately (as seen in https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#method-query-parameterized)

I try to write a `plsql` function that does the bulk insert and send all the data in an array (or in a string, I try boths):

```
client.query("select bulk_insert", [allTheData], cb);
```

And I obtain the following message:

```
index row requires 38656 bytes, maximum size is 8191
```

**Notes**

- The database is in other server
- I only be able to connect with de postgres port
- I'm not able to execute something like `sh psql < "COPY..."`

How can I do the bulk insert sending the data separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look to a plugin from the same author, as you database client library: https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams which exactly made for `COPY` command.

Comment: from json object rather than file !